# How to disable link on a node title?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm using Drupal 7. I want disable link on some node-title.

Like disable ''Link this field to the original piece of content'' in Views.

How can i do this? For example, via template.php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that makes that happen is in [node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7):

```
<?php if (!$page): ?>
<h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
  <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>">
    <?php print $title; ?>
  </a>
</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So to override it, you just need to re-create node.tpl.php somewhere in your theme's folder, remove the `<a>` tag surrounding the title, and clear Drupal's caches. Then you won't get links on title for node teasers any more.

If this is too 'all-encompassing' and you just want to do it for a specific content type then as well as copying the original (unchanged) node.tpl.php into your theme's folder, create another one called, for example, node--article.tpl.php (for the article content type), and make the alterations in there instead.

Comment: Now, i must create node--node--20.tpl.php and override your code, right?

Comment: According to the [Drupal 7 Theme Hook Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) it would be `node--20.tpl.php`. I think you might be thinking of `page--node--20.tpl.php` which would be the page template, not the node

Comment: Ok sorry but my node.tpl file is: http://pastebin.com/tg16M1Uu

Comment: Just replace `$title_link` with `$title`, that should sort it